# Calculate diary earnings from an instrument

Tags: r

I wanna calculate the diary earnings from the price of an instrument.

```
instrument=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
price=c(12,13,29,20,87,24,14,78,46,98,23,67,25,88,27)
date=c("2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-03","2019-04-03","2019-04-03","2019-04-03","2019-04-03")
tabla1=data.frame(instrument,price,date)
```

I want to know how can i calculate how much money i earn from the instrument 1 between date 2019-04-01 and 2019-04-02

Comment: Do you mean daily? In any case, please show a sample of what you have tried and why it has failed. There are many questions that achieve the same. `group-fun` style.

Comment: can you clarify the question with an example calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would like the daily return as `p(t) / p(t-1) - 1`, then:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(tabla1)
dt[, return := price / shift(price) - 1, by = .(instrument)]
```